# Proper way to isolate all elements under an element from external styles of project

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I just included a new js calendar in my project. The calendar displays like this -

```
<div style="position: absolute;" id="container">
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" class="DynarchCalendar-topCont">         
       <tbody>
          <tr><td>
             // lots of elements inside
          <td><tr>
       </tbody>
     </table></div>
```

The problem is that the view of the calendar is appearing distorted due to some styles in my project like this -

```
div#sel_filters div.fields div {
    margin-left: 10px;
}

div.filters div.fields div {
    float: left;
    padding: 7px 0 0;
}
... and many more which apply to the elements inside
```

There are many css files of the project. Since my calendar appears inside div.fields, the above styles apply to it as well. I am not considering altering the above project styles , as they may affect others.

What is the proper clean way of not allowing any styles other than those in the `jscalendar.css` file to affect it. DO I only have this option of applying !important to the styles in the `jscalendar.css`, and searching all the extra attributes, which are only set by project css, and setting them 0 or null manually.

In case it matters, I am free to include the jscalendar.css before/after project css files.

Answer (score 0):

If you load your jscalendar.css after the other CSS files it should overwrite the other CSS directives. 
If you still have problems, you could add a class to the divs that should behave differently and then add a CSS directive after the others to overwrite the previous ones:

```
div.filters div.fields div.yourClass {
    float: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: this will still cause issues in the future with specificity

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to do this unfortunately is to fix your site's CSS. What you're doing by applying styles to elements directly such as `div`'s is going to lead to a world of pain for future maintenance or changes.

Avoid styling elements directly at all costs, use classes as much as possible, then IDs. Use elements with classes or IDs like `div.foo` or `div#foo` but not elements directly.

You could get away with !important in your calendar CSS for now but I'd spend that time fixing your site's CSS, as if ever you upgrade the calendar plugin you're looking at painful times again.

So take the hit now, look at the positive of having learnt how to do things properly and never repeat the same mistake again :)

Answer (score 0):

apply a unique id to the container and change your CSS to reflect the heritage that derives from that... direct styling will get you to where you wanna go, but its gonna cost you in the long run if you have to maintain this later down the road...

but i must agree with Moin Zaman, if you hit this obstacle, its bound to happen again if you dont take care of it right now